# How I can add method to use ‘in’ with my class obj in python 3?

Tags: python

How can I add method, which allowed to use `in` With my class aa?

```
class aa:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)
    def __add__(self,other):
        x=self.x+other
        return aa(x)

a=aa(2)
print(2 in a) # error: “...arg not iterable”
```

Comment: @jpp, the one about iterators is not a duplicate as it is not what OP is asking about (you can't us `in` with iterators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `__contains__` for you class.

See more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).

```
class aa:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)
    def __add__(self,other):
        x=self.x+other
        return aa(x)
    def __contains__(self,x):
        # TODO implement  
        pass
```

Comment: Though it is not required, it is a good idea for a class that you intend to use as a container be a subclass of `collections.abc.Container`.  Your readers and your IDE will better understand your intent.  In addition, Python will give you an error if you forget to define `__contains__` or accidentally. misspell it.